# MySQL Select and Delete Row

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a cron job I need to run every minute to check a database table. The table consists of two fields (username, lastping). lastping is a mysql datetime object that is set by another script using the mysql `NOW()` function. I need to check lastping to see if it has been over a minute since it was last updated, if it hasn't been updated in the last minute, I want to delete the row containing that username and lastping. I figure I can check using something like this sql statement.

```
FROM client WHERE lastping < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE;
```

My question is, how do I format the select statement to do this check for the entire table and delete the record if it has been over a minute.

I'll be updating the database every 15-30 seconds for users who are still connected. The whole purpose of this is to allow me to see which end-users are using my C++ application at that moment, or at least within the past 60 seconds, so I can keep statistics.

This is what I'm doing so far, the output is Deleted inactive users but this does not actually happen.

```
mysql_connect(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(DATABASE);
$query="DELETE (username, lastping) from client where lastping < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
echo "Deleted inactive users";
```

Comment: You need to research how to delete rows with conditions. It's in the MySQL manual. [Read it sometime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).

Comment: Don't you want "less than" instead? `WHERE lastping < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE` (i.e., where `lastping` is _before_ one minute ago)?

Comment: `delete from client where lastping > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE` ? The answer was almost in the question. Or I misunderstood what you wanted to achieve

Comment: Sorry, typo on the less than.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete and select rows in one query. There is no way to "return" or "select" the rows you have deleted.

You may want to use transaction then, where you would be executing two queries in a single transaction.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html